# How to remove snippets from Aptana or give precedence to Emmet

Tags: aptana

When I use Emmet and press c TAB I get a Copyright instead of color.

I have searched in the snippets for the word Copyright but I have not found no related sniped.
I treed looking under Preferences > Keys and search for Zen or Tab, but I don't know how I can set precedence to Emmet. When going to Command > HTML /CSS>Edit this bundle noting happens

Does anyone know how I can remove all snippets from Aptana or give precedence to Emmet (Zen Coding).

Answer (score 0):

The Copyright Snippet is found in the Text Bundle. To disable it, go to `Commands > Text > Edit this Bundle`. This will create a new Project in the Project Explorer view. Inside the project, under snippets, is a file called snippets.rb in which you will find the code that supports the copyright snippet. Comment it out or delete it, save the file, and restart Aptana. `c)` should no longer make the Copyright snippet.

Comment: I have found the snippet and chanced it  s.trigger = 'copy' but still when I press C tab I get the copyright

Comment: Did you save the file and restart Aptana?

Comment: Yes, it reacts to c and cop tab  
I have edit in two locations  
E:\Users\name\Aptana Rubles  
E:\Users\name\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_2102077185\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\98\1\.cp\bundles